# How to use Selenium Webdriver headless mode while waiting for an element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, headless-browser

So my question is, how can I use headless mode while waiting for the visibility of an element? While waiting for a map to load, for example, is it possible?

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element_css"))).get_attribute("value")
```

I've tried using `options.add_argument('--headless')` but it doesn't find the element.

Comment: do you have this problem without `'--headless'` ?

Comment: nope, only when I use it

Comment: because the object is never actually available to view

Comment: you didn't show URL for page which makes problem so we can't test it - and we can't help you.